# Currency According to Country in android

Tags: java, android, currency

I want to show Currency symbol according to current gps location.
How can I  do this?
I am using below code but it always returns $.

```
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
Address obj = addresses.get(0);
Currency cc=Currency.getInstance(obj.getLocale());
```

Comment: Have you checked that obj returns different locales for different addresses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the following to obtain the symbol for currency?

```
 Currency.getInstance(obj.getLocale()).getSymbol();
```

Is your obj.getLocale() a valid locale code following [ISO_3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3) and
[ISO 639-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) like "de_DE". Further more have you assured, that your testdevice supports the required locales? 
More information for locales [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html).