# How to get a Currency symbol based on GPS location or Country code

Tags: java, android, gps

I have implemented a mini project and there i need to display currency symbol based on Location. 
ex: If i am in India it should display rupee symbol if USA $ symbol, I have implemented but it always gives Pound symbol

My Code:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(ListActivity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (loc != null) {
    Geocoder code = new Geocoder(ListActivity.this);
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = code.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        String cc = Currency.getInstance(obj.getLocale()).getSymbol();

        Log.d("Currency Symbol : ", cc);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Above code will always give phone locale currency.

Comment: Can u suggest me how to get symbol..?

Comment: Instead pass current locale like
Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
but this method wont be applicable for gps.

Comment: Please refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400066/currency-according-to-country-in-android

Comment: Its any method but i need to display a Currency symbol based on location or ip or gps. Can u edit my code

Answer (score 2):

---

I needed to show currency symbol of respective country and get country are from GPS i searched lot finally came up with below code its working properly so i want to share this code others could not waste there time

---

here you need first country code like IN,US from latitude longitude we get full address

---

Please check GPS permission in manifest file before run code.
below are the some permissions

---

need GPSTracker.java file code create GPSTracker java file and write below code. in this some red line dont worry it affect nothing

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // Flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // Flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // Flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // Location
    double latitude; // Latitude
    double longitude; // Longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // Getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // No network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // If GPS enabled, get latitude/longitude using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }


    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app.
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            //locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }


    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/Wi-Fi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }


    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog.
     * On pressing the Settings button it will launch Settings Options.
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing the Settings button.
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // On pressing the cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    @
    Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}


    @
    Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}


    @
    Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}


    @
    Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}


    @
    Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

### here is mainactivity.java class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static SortedMap < Currency, Locale > currencyLocaleMap;
    TextView t;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    private static final Map < String, Locale > COUNTRY_TO_LOCALE_MAP = new HashMap < String, Locale > ();
    static {
        Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        for (Locale l: locales) {
            COUNTRY_TO_LOCALE_MAP.put(l.getCountry(), l);
        }
    }
    public static Locale getLocaleFromCountry(String country) {
        return COUNTRY_TO_LOCALE_MAP.get(country);
    }

    String Currencysymbol = "";

    @
    Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
        geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, getLocaleFromCountry(""));
        double lat = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
        double lng = gpsTracker.getLongitude();

        Log.e("Lat long ", lng + "lat long check" + lat);


        currencyLocaleMap = new TreeMap < Currency, Locale > (new Comparator < Currency > () {
              public int compare(Currency c1, Currency c2) {
                  return c1.getCurrencyCode().compareTo(c2.getCurrencyCode());
              }
          });

          for (Locale locale: Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
              try {
                  Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
                  currencyLocaleMap.put(currency, locale);

                  Log.d("locale utill", currency + " locale1 " + locale.getCountry());

              } catch (Exception e) {

                  Log.d("locale utill", "e" + e);
              }
          }


          try {

              List < Address > addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 2);
              Address obj = addresses.get(0);
              Currencysymbol = getCurrencyCode(obj.getCountryCode());

              Log.e("getCountryCode", "Exception address " + obj.getCountryCode());
              Log.e("Currencysymbol", "Exception address " + Currencysymbol);

          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("Exception address", "Exception address" + e);
              // Log.e("Currencysymbol","Exception address"+Currencysymbol);
        }
        t.setText(Currencysymbol);
    }

    public String getCurrencyCode(String countryCode) {

        String s = "";
        for (Locale locale: Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
            try {

                if (locale.getCountry().equals(countryCode)) {

                    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
                    currencyLocaleMap.put(currency, locale);
                    Log.d("locale utill", currency + " locale1 " + locale.getCountry() + "s " + s);
                    s = getCurrencySymbol(currency + "");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("locale utill", "e" + e);
            }
        }
        return s;
    }

    public String getCurrencySymbol(String currencyCode) {
        Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);
        System.out.println(currencyCode + ":-" + currency.getSymbol(currencyLocaleMap.get(currency)));
        return currency.getSymbol(currencyLocaleMap.get(currency));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

**You can use this to get locale of your Location**

```
Locale locale= getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
Currency currency=Currency.getInstance(locale);
String symbol = currency.getSymbol();
```

**Refernce** : [Getting Current Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389349/android-get-current-locale-not-default)

Comment: It is giving £ symbol it should display rupee symbol as per location

Comment: He was not asking for the device locale. He wants a locale (or country or currency symbol) by given latitude, longitude coordinate