# Get currency symbol by device's location

Tags: java, geolocation, location, symbols, currency

I am trying to get the currency symbol of the location the device running the program is currently in (or at least where it is registered to be, I am not looking to forcibly know the location via IP or GPS like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779168/how-to-get-a-currency-symbol-based-on-gps-location-or-country-code) something, just the System's location).

I have seen several methods of extracting currency name by a so - called "country code"

but I am looking to get the symbol - and I want to do it without hard - coding the country but rather getting it in run time from the user and thus country codes are not an option. also, I can't use third party libraries.

Thanks!

Comment: can you bring back your answer? I am trying to understand it and it got deleted....

Comment: Really, this question is “How go I get Locale object by geolocation?”. If you have a `Locale` object, you can ask `Currency` object for the appropriate symbol.

Comment: @BasilBourque should I edit the ask the question you suggest? I don't want being accused of asking a X Y problem. So I provided the full scope.

Comment: You could edit, as there are no Answers posted yet. But that was not my intent, I was just giving a hint to others reading the Question.